# Does cuSolverDN or another CUDA library have a batched-version of QR decomposition for dense matrices to solve A*x = b?

Tags: cuda, cusolver, qr-decomposition

I'm trying to solve A*x = b where A has complex values and is dense.

I used cusolverDnCgeqrf() method from cuSolverDN library to do the QR decomposition for one linear set of equations.  However, I want to do this several times to speed up the processing.

Is there a "batched" version of this method?  Or is there another CUDA library I can use?

Comment: "Is there a "batched" version of this method?"  Have you looked at the cusolver [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#cuds-function-reference) ?  "Or is there another CUDA library I can use?"  From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Comment: This might help: 
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/openmp-cublas-for-batched-matrix-solves-using-lu/127265

Answer (score 2):

You can use Magma batched QR:
http://icl.cs.utk.edu/projectsfiles/magma/doxygen/group__group__qr__batched.html#details

Or Nvidia batched library:
https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/parallel-direct-solvers-with-cusolver-batched-qr/

I am not sure if there are python wrappers for them yet.
I want to add that batched version of many solvers are currently available, either through Magma or Nvidia.

There is not a single standard yet, but it is underway, it is discussed in batched blas workshops:
here

http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/WEB-PAGES/Batched-BLAS-2017/
and here:

http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/WEB-PAGES/Batched-BLAS-2016/

The draft is ready and I hope there would be a standard Batched BLAS soon.